# Posting HTML form to new wp database table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to make a HTML form post the input values to a custom table in the WordPress database. I've managed to get something to show up in a new row, but almost all of my values return `N;` instead of the value from the form.

Here's the code I have in my page template:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;

$userID = $current_user->ID;
$brand = serialize($_POST["brand"]);
$url = serialize($_POST["url"]);
$sector = serialize($_POST["sector"]);
$keywords = serialize($_POST["keywords"]);
if ( 
'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateSearch' ) {
        $ufDataUpdate = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_wct3', array( 
        'date' => current_time('mysql'),
        'userid' => $userID,
        'brand' => $brand,
        'url' => $url, 
        'sector' => $sector,
        'keywords' => $keywords ) );
        }
       ?>

<form method="post">


<label for="brand">Brand/Product Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="brand" placeholder="eg: Spidr" class="clearfix" required />
    <label for="website">Website address: </label>
    <input type="url" id="url" placeholder="eg: www.spidr.co.uk" class="clearfix" required />
    <label for="sector">Market sector: </label>
    <input type="text" id="sector" placeholder="eg: Internet Marketing Tools" class="clearfix" required />
    <label for="keyword">Keywords/Phrases:<br><span class="orange">(comma separated)</span></label>
    <textarea cols="0" rows="8" class="light" id="keywords" required></textarea>


    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button-65 mobile-button" value="release the spiders!">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateSearch' ); ?>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateSearch" />

</form>
```

Where `wp_wct3` is the database name and each item in the array is the name of each column in that table.

I'm not sure if my issue lies in this code, or in the set-up of the database itself. I've used the [Wordpress custom tables plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-tables/) to make the new table. The brand, url and sector simply use the `text` definition, while the keywords use `enum('0','1')`.

Anyone have any ideas why the values aren't returning and I'm just getting `N;` ?

Comment: Okay, I made a bit of a mistake in the form! I forgot to add the `name` value so that my PHP can pick it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the main issue. I'd missed out the `name` attribute from the form itself, so my PHP wasn't picking up the field values!

Answer (score 1):

```
this is my custom-form template.. it works for me

<?php
/**
Template Name: Custom-Form
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
        global $wpdb;
            $table = wp_achord;
            $data = array(
                'name' => $_POST['yourname'],
                'chord'    => $_POST['chord']
            );
            $format = array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            );
            $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
            if($success){
            echo 'data has been save' ; 
}
}
else   {
?>
        <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="yourname">
        <textarea name="chord"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

       <?php }  ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```